# How to identify allowed user google calendar api authorization request gmail account

Tags: c#, calendar, google-api, authorization, google-calendar-api

I need to find the user response for  authorised request in identification to his gmail account, Actually am trying to send mail regarding the authentication from developers account to users. When user clicks Allow then calendar events are created in their calendar.

But when they deny, Exception pops out stating Not authorised user. I need to find the user mail id and what user doing accepting or denying ? Yeah I tried 
[this link](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=youraccess_token)

Example :

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=ya29.Ci82A9-AcdxxjkatYj5NxwaxmJJybeOq7JwqhBUOCYpFM9xpBKHrWlEVULea4OfM_Q

but i am getting error:

```
   {
     "error": {
     "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "reason":  "insufficientPermissions",
          "message": "Insufficient Permission"
        }
        ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Insufficient Permission"
    }
  }
```

Need Assistance Guys.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the above access_token "ya29.Ci82A9-AcdxxjkatYj5NxwaxmJJybeOq7JwqhBUOCYpFM9xpBKHrWlEVULea4OfM_Q" at the first place?

If you provide the proper auth scope and add along "email" (perhaps also "profile" or "openid") in the scope string, you will be able to retrieve the authenticated user's email address (and other profile/openid details).

Anyway, I suspect the issue you encountered is due to the incorrect scope being specified.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Comment: Scope is working fine  @some1 but i am unable to find the User Account Email.

Comment: you should change `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` to `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar%20openid%20email` (i.e. adding along the additional "email" & "openid" scopes). with that, you will get an "id_token" in the response. the email address is embedded in tahat "id_token". refer to the above URL for the detailed reference and example.

Answer (score 0):

I requested for this

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&client_id=69959946055-4128vlomr0vlm7tnnbs3cv0banppe90n.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.google.co.in&response_type=token

I got the response

https://www.google.co.in/#access_token=ya29.Ci82A-6MUVXaOQ1Hi1znc3wBF8Dm_iaI6OXjJtDvmK3NRB0DFYZNq221v7YU1QHwJA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

from the above response i copied the access token and requested for 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=ya29.Ci82A-6MUVXaOQ1Hi1znc3wBF8Dm_iaI6OXjJtDvmK3NRB0DFYZNq221v7YU1QHwJA
Its not because of scope. The url is working but i am unable to find the User Account Email id.

Comment: How to find the Account details in this scenario ?